# Windows Server 2012 R2 Smart card limit

Tags: windows, smartcard, windows-server-2012-r2, pcsc

Afternoon all

We've got an application that runs on Windows Server that requires upto 50 smartcard's to be connected to the host application server.
This works without any issues on our existing Server 2003/2008 installations.

However when we've come to test the application on Server 2012 R2, only 10 smartcards show up. All the USB devices are recognised correctly, however our pcsc test app can only find 10 terminals.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any known fixes?

Cheers
Gavin

Comment: I am just curious: what is your use case with so many devices connected to the single system? BTW maybe you could get the answer on serverfault.com.

Comment: Use case is smart cards as a security and verification device used by our application. I'll try server fault though :-)

Comment: @fatncgav did you find solution?

Comment: No, we never did find a solution.

Comment: I wonder if this could be got around with something like a Yubikey that doesn't require a dedicated card reader.

Comment: i'll add another use-case: factory flashing and testing certain crypto-processors...usually done in a fixture with multiple boards.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is a windows limitation, and i don't think that there is or will be any solution for this.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3144446/limitation-of-10-smart-card-readers-in-windows-server-2012-r2,-windows-8,-and-later